# SocketIO & ReactJs: Socket Emitting multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, socket.io, use-effect

My client is responding multiple times when my server emits an event.
By reading other available SOF answers, it seems like I must have duplicated the event listeners somewhere in my code.

I actually have other socket listeners in the same file, and they all (?) seem to be functioning fine.
I've tried moving the listener out of the `useEffect` to see if it works, but it has the same issue.

I've tried to limit the listener to socket.once, however, there is an additional issue -
`user` is not defined on the first emit.
Only the second emit then `user` is defined...

Client:

```
const getUserInfo= async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/user/info', axiosConfig);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
}

const App = ({ socket, clientId }) => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    user: undefined,
  });


  const checkAuthentication = async () => {
    const user= await getUserInfo();

    localStorage.setItem('user.email', user.email);
    setState({ ...state, user});
    return true;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const onMount = async () => {
      const authed = await checkAuthentication()
    };

    onMount();
  }, []);

  userEffect(() => {
  socket.on("allInfo", async ({ requester }) => { //This catches multiple times
    console.log(`Admin ${requester} requested for tablet information.`)
    const user= { ...state.user};

    socket.emit('infoPayload', { user);  //thus this emits multiple times.
  })
}, [state.user])


  return (
    <>
      <Route exact path="/"
        render={() => <div>{state.user&& state.user.email}</div>}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default (App);
```

Comment: your socket event handling looks backwards/really strange.  in general you need to put that `socket.on()` inside the `useEffect()` above (with the empty array) and could just add an `if ( state.user ) { ... }` around the emit.   but really this doesn't track well without knowing what each thing is doing and expecting in return.  why is `allInfo` waiting for a socket message just to do an emit of the user data?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I initially thought I should wrap it in a useEffect that only runs after state.user is defined, but perhaps that was a wrong impression. `allInfo` is actually is an event where the admins (from another frontend) requesting for user information. Hence, on `allinfo` request, the client fires back all information

Comment: well `state.user` here will first be undefined, then it will have something on its next change, so that's two calls to `socket.on()` right there.  if you wanted to handle this reliant on it you could leave it in the array and in the effect only call `socket.on()` inside a `if ( state.user ) { ... }`.  add a `socket.off('allInfo')` just before the `.on` and you can manage it as the user changes (if necessary).

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! However, if turn the code into the following ```useEffect(() => {
    ...
    if (state.driver) {
      socket.on("allInfo", async ({ requester }) => {
        socket.emit('infoPayload', { user });
      })
    }
    
  }, []);```

Then since the effect only runs when it mounts, the event wouldn't fire at all